# Adding a comboBoxcolumn to datatable in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

**Question**
How can I add a comboBoxcolumn to a dataTable and not just the grid?  I tried setting the "Connector Name" column to be a comboboxcolumn , but apparently I'm not doing it right.

**What I have**  (snippet):

```
  if (_DtMain.Columns.Count == 0)
            {

                var cols = new List<DataColumn>();
                cols.Add(new DataColumn("PocketName", typeof(string)));
                cols.Add(new DataColumn("KeyIndex", typeof(string)));
                cols.Add(new DataColumn("SortOrder", typeof(int)));
                cols.Add(new DataColumn("ConnectorName", typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxColumn )));
                _DtMain.Columns.AddRange(cols.ToArray());
                dataGridView1.DataSource = _DtMain.DefaultView;

            }
```

**Edit**

Here's my new solution:

```
    if (_DtMain.Columns.Count == 0)
    {
        var colPN = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        var colCN = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        var colKI = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        var colSO = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

        dgvHeaderEdit.Columns.Add(colPN);
        dgvHeaderEdit.Columns.Add(colCN);
        dgvHeaderEdit.Columns.Add(colKI);
        dgvHeaderEdit.Columns.Add(colSO);

        colPN.HeaderText = "Pocket Name";
        colPN.DataPropertyName = "Pocket Name";

        colCN.HeaderText = "Connector Name";
        colCN.DataPropertyName = "Connector Name";

        colKI.HeaderText = "Key Index";
        colKI.DataPropertyName = "Key Index";

        colSO.HeaderText = "Sort Order";
        colSO.DataPropertyName = "Sort Order";

        _DtMain.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Pocket Name", typeof(string)));
        _DtMain.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Connector Name", typeof(string)));
        _DtMain.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Key Index", typeof(string)));
        _DtMain.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sort Order", typeof(int)));


 dgvHeaderEdit.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                dgvHeaderEdit.DataSource = _DtMain.DefaultView;
```

Comment: why do you want to add `ComboBox` to a `DataTable`? Try using a `Collection` object

Comment: `col.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SomeCollection", typeof(List<string>)));`

Comment: @MethodMan  The column doesn't show using cols.Add(new DataColumn("ConnectorName", typeof(List<string>)));

Comment: Here's a working way of doing what I wanted.  I just did the columns for the datatable and grid programmically and added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use It this way : 
When Building the dataTable for the DataSource of Grid :

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("PocketName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("KeyIndex", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("SortOrder", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("ConnectorName", typeof(int));

            dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

Now Create A ComboBox Column For GridView & a Datasource For this ComboBox.
Add All Values to display in ComboBox in dtConnectorSource 
Fill the dtConnectorSource with values you need in the ComboBox.

```
DataTable dtConnectorSource = new DataTable();

dtConnectorSource.Columns.Add("ConnectorName", typeof(int));
dtConnectorSource.Columns.Add("ConnectorNameDisplay", typeof(String));

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ();
    cmb.DataSource = dtConnectorSource;
    cmb.DisplayMember = "ConnectorNameDisplay";
    cmb.ValueMember = "ConnectorName";

    cmb.DataPropertyName = "ConnectorName";

    dgv.Columns.Add(cmb);
```